# Xamarin Forms ListView Custom Cell determine clicked column or control

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I get a bunch of hits when I search for this, but I have ended up going down rabbit holes that were [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)-specific or something like that.

My environment is Xamarin Forms Android, iOS, and [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform). It is something of an experimental/educational project, so there are no totally "hard" requirements for a solution. The ItemTappedEventArgs gives me the contents of the row, but not the specific item or column.

If the user taps on a particular item in a ListView ViewCell, how can I determine which specific column or control they tapped?

Here's the relevant XAML content (RowStyle has only appearance properties like FontSize and Margin):

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CodeTable}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped" x:Name="ListViewCodeTable" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CodeTableRow">
            <ViewCell >
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Khaki" VerticalOptions="Start" MinimumHeightRequest="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding Decimal}" Style="{StaticResource RowStyle}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding Hex}" Style="{StaticResource RowStyle}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Ascii}" Style="{StaticResource RowStyle}" FontAttributes="{Binding AttribAscii}" />
etc.
```

Comment: ItemTapped operates at the Cell level.  If you want a tap within the cell, add a gesture recognizer to that specific element

Comment: ListView have SelectedItem property you will get the value of tapped item in that

Comment: @Divyesh_08 on Android it seems that SelectedItem is not populated on a Tapped event, but I was able to cast the sender appropriately and get the information I needed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using SelectedItem like here

```xml
<ListView x:Name="dataList" ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
          HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"        
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
</ListView>
```

**In ViewModel**

```csharp
private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem {
    get {return _selectedItem; } 
    set 
    { 
        _selectedItem = value;
        // Additional code
    }
}
```

**Using ItemTapped you have to handle it from xaml.cs page:**

```xml
<ListView x:Name="dataList" ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
          HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"        
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="MyItemTapped">
</ListView>
```

**In code behind**

```csharp
private async void MyItemTapped(object sender,  ItemTapEventArgs e)
{
    var content = e.Item as MyModel;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new somePage(content));
}
```